# Implement CNN+LSTM Model to predict a video

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

Hi guys i already making my model for cnn(alexNet)+lstm model for prediction in a video to check from 10 frames to make a prediction
but i still confused by how to code the program to check the frame first and how to resize it correctly so every video that i input can be checked by this model

here's some of the **code** that has been made

```
while vid.isOpened():
    ret, frame = vid.read()
    if ret == True:
      frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
      scale_percent = 20 # percent of original size
      width = int(frame.shape[1] * scale_percent / 100)
      height = int(frame.shape[0] * scale_percent / 100)
      dim = (width, height)
      frame_set = cv2.resize(frame, dim, interpolation = cv2.INTER_AREA)
      pred = model.predict(frame_set)
      texto = pred(frame)
      frame = cv2.putText(frame,str(texto),(0,130), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, (255, 255, 255), 3)
      cv2.imshow('Video', frame)

      if cv2.waitKey(25) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        break
      else:
        break

vid.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

but I still got error because my resize isn't the same as my model ask

> ```
> ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer model_1: expected shape=(None, 10, 299, 299, 3), found shape=(None, 384)
> ```

it asks just like when i made my model when 10 is how much frame that my model need to predict

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The input shape of your Alexnet model is (None, 10, 299, 299, 3), while your frame_set sample has size (None, 384). You should modify the input shape of your model to be (384) (for example, by adding one first layer (Input((384,))), even though I guess Alexnet is better suited for images. However I cannot tell you how to do that since I don't see the model definition

Comment: hi jackve thank you for your reply, so i need to make the model suit my testing input viode instead resize my testing input video ?

Comment: hi jackve i did try what you suggest but sadly its still doesnt work since the model that i made are (batch, timesteps, h, w, channel) when my code in this post are still for (batch, h, w, channel), still finding some clue how to add the timesteps on this code post for the implementation model, but thank you for your answer it did help me understand a lot !